# sqlite string locate

Tags: string, sqlite, locate

What is the syntax in SQLite to get all values which contains given string?

I tried:
SELECT columnName FROM tableName WHERE LOCATE(string,columnName)!=0;
but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT columnName FROM tableName WHERE columnname LIKE '%string%'
```